# How to change Integer 20200224 to date 24/02/2020 in Spotfire (Expression ?)

Tags: spotfire-analyst

In spotfire I have a loaded column with integer 20200224 I would like to change this to date 24/02/2020 with a transformation and expression ( or an other way if possible) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParseDate` and `String` to change an integer to a Date. Then change the format to a custom `'d/M/yyyy'` when creating the calculated column.

```
ParseDate(String([IntDate]),"yyyyMMdd" )
```

> Parses a date from a string to a Date format. The first argument is a
> string or a string column containing a date.
>
> The second argument is a format string explaining how the date is
> built up and the third (optional) argument is a culture code.
>
> Examples: ParseDate("2013-09-17", "yyyy-MM-dd")
> ParseDate("17-okt-2013","dd-MMM-yyyy","sv-SE")

[image: Example]